# How does spring boot find the path of the META-INF/spring.factories

Tags: spring-boot

I am learning how spring boot auto-configuration works and I have known that spring boot can scan all jars to find the files named `META-INF/spring.factories`.

But I am confused about how does the spring boot decide the path to scan.

It scans all `.jars` in the maven repository or somewhere else？

I can‘t find the detail in the source code，can anyone help me figure it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It definitely will not scan the whole maven repository. Instead ,it scans from the [class-path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) only which the paths are normally specified when the application starts.

For the source codes , you can refer to [`SpringFactoriesLoader.loadSpringFactories()`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/bc205e0dbf4b79e9dd2f3527ddfa9fb5a117cc67/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/io/support/SpringFactoriesLoader.java#L132)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I start the application as a eureka server, how does spring boot find the `META-INF/spring.factories` in the `spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server.jar`. Because I think it has a different class-path.

Comment: because when you start the application , you need to specify the eureka-server.jar to be on the classpath..

Comment: Thanks a lot, the IDE automatically adds `-classpath` args, and I ignored this message.